# how do I put my python into my website

Tags: python-3.x, web, matplotlib

How do I put my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fib(nooftimes):
    repeat=nooftimes
    a=1
    print(a)
    b=1
    print(b)
    r="ratio between"
    print(r,a/b)
    odd=[1]
    even=[]
    dtg=[1]
    fack=1
    counter1=1
    counter2=0
    counter3=0
    while nooftimes>0:
        c=a+b
        print(c)
        e=c/b
        counter1=counter1+1
        if(counter1%2==0):
            even.append(e)
        if(counter1%2==1):
            odd.append(e)
        dtg.append(e)
        print(r,e)
        a=b+c
        f=a/c
        counter1=counter1+1
        if(counter1%2==0):
            even.append(f)
        if(counter1%2==1):
            odd.append(f)
        dtg.append(f)
        print(a)
        print(r,f)
        b=c+a
        g=b/a
        counter1=counter1+1
        if(counter1%2==0):
            even.append(e)
        if(counter1%2==1):
            odd.append(e)
        dtg.append(g)
        print(b)
        print(r,g)
        nooftimes=nooftimes-1
    else:
        plt.plot(dtg)
        plt.plot(even)
        plt.plot(odd)
        plt.ylabel('stuff')
        plt.show()

fib(5)
```

into my website?

Do I have to use some sort of api or something to do it?

Comment: what webserver are you using?

Comment: One way of producing plots in webpages would be [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/). It can be run as a server-side application or statically in a html page. I would suggest you have a look at some of the examples.